# I want to change letters to numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I want to convert a string of letters to corresponding numbers on the alphabet with the inclusion of space for zero

```
def letters_to_numbers(message):

    change = {
        " ":0,
        "a":1,
        "b":2,
        "c":3,
        "d":4,
        "e":5,
        "f":6,
        "g":7,
        "h":8,
        "i":9,
        "j":10,
        "k":11,
        "l":12,
        "m":13,
        "n":14,
        "o":15,
        "p":16,
        "q":17,
        "r":18,
        "s":19,
        "t":20,
        "u":21,
        "v":22,
        "w":23,
        "x":24,
        "y":25,
        "z":26
    }

    arr = []

    for k,j in change.items():
        for i in message:
            if k==i:
                arr.append(j)
                print(arr)
```

I expect letters_to_numbers('one ball') to be [15,14,5,0,2,1,12,12] instead I get [0,1,2,5,12,12,14,15]

Comment: using the `string` library, you could get the `change dict` as `dict(zip(' ' + string.ascii_lowercase, [ord(c)%32 for c in ' ' + string.ascii_lowercase]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate over `message` and pick out the corresponding number from `change`. The function can be reduced to a simple list-comprehension.

```
def letters_to_numbers(message):

    change = {
        " ":0,
        "a":1,
        "b":2,
        "c":3,
        "d":4,
        "e":5,
        "f":6,
        "g":7,
        "h":8,
        "i":9,
        "j":10,
        "k":11,
        "l":12,
        "m":13,
        "n":14,
        "o":15,
        "p":16,
        "q":17,
        "r":18,
        "s":19,
        "t":20,
        "u":21,
        "v":22,
        "w":23,
        "x":24,
        "y":25,
        "z":26
    }
    return [change[k] for k in message]

print(letters_to_numbers('one ball'))
```

Output:

```
[15, 14, 5, 0, 2, 1, 12, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ord() to convert the letters to their ASCII number and from there you can convert it to this set of numbers.

```
ord('a') = 97
```

But you want a to be mapped to 1, so do

```
ord('a')-96 = 1
```

Here is the sample code,

```
def fun(letter):
 if letter == '':
   return 0
 elif letter.islower():
   return ord(letter) - 96
 elif letter.isupper():
   return ord(letter)-64
```